# GPU usage at 1% during training Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm new to Tensorflow and i'm trying to train a model for which I am using an ImageDataGenerator:

```
data_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

BATCH_SIZE = 32

train_gen = data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
    mapping_train,
    x_col = 'path',
    y_col = 'label',
    target_size = (256, 256),
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
)
```

`mapping_train` is a dataframe that contains the path_to_image and class_label columns.

I'm applying transfer learning using VGG16 and calling the fit_generator method as:

```
model_1.fit_generator(train_gen,
                      steps_per_epoch=mapping_train.shape[0] / BATCH_SIZE,
                      epochs=3
                     )
```

However, my GPU is only at less than 2% at all times but my VRAM usage is almost full (4GB) with a batch size of 32.

TensorFlow does recognize my GPU and calling `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`  prints GTX 1050Ti on my console.

I have tried:

- Increasing batch_size: Caused OOM error
- Tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47463582/11971720) by using `use_multiprocessing = True` and `workers = 4`
- Tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63152887/11971720) by casting my labels into np.uint8

None of them worked. Would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: It may very well be that controlling the execution (CPU) or memory (VRAM) is the bottleneck in that model.

Comment: Not sure if it has nothing to do with your issue, but .fit_generator is deprecated, you should use .fit instead.